# Hooking methods in another process with Moles

Tags: c#, .net, moles, pex-and-moles, api-hook

I have a C# application compiled with visual studio. I want to intercept and log calls and serialized method parameters to some specific methods in that app. Is it possible to intercept method calls in another process (maybe by using App domains?).

In other words, I want to achieve similar goal in .NET as madCodeHook and Detours does for win32.

Answer (score 1):

For multiprocessor programming it's easier using MPI (Message Passing Interface).

Try to look into [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx).

Comment: Sorry but looks like you didn't understand my question. What does multiprocessor programming has to do with API/method hooking?

Comment: From that you should start. It can be done only with unmanaged code and refers to hacking section. You need to analize program, and extract function address in memory (than you can call this function). About hacking you can read in special sites. It is significant that your program in this case must be executed with the ring 0 (access privileges). My ansver is useful?